# Drag and Drop of item in same Gridview with repositioning

Tags: android, android-gridview

I have a requirement of creating drag and drop feature in same Gridview.
Where items can be rearranged automatically after dropping it to particular position.
I have tried

[blahti's drag and drop](https://github.com/thquinn/DraggableGridView)

[thQuinn's drag drop](https://github.com/thquinn/DraggableGridView)

[mrKlar's drag drop with pagination](https://github.com/mrKlar/PagedDragDropGrid)

but none of them fully satisfy my requirements.

As i want to develop reordering other than drag and drop also.

I am open for any kind of suggestions.

Comment: try this library https://github.com/mrKlar/PagedDragDropGrid